# customize celery task formatter

Tags: logging, celery

I have a Celery task for which I would like to customize the log formatter, based on argument received by the task (so the argument is different for every task).

Is this the good approach?

```py
from celery.app.log import TaskFormatter
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

from mycode import celery_app

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

@celery_app.task(ignore_results=True, bind=True)
def task_do_something(self, a):
    b = get_some_value(a)
    for handler in logger.handlers:
        handler.setFormatter(
            TaskFormatter(
                 "[%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s/%(processName)s]"
                 " %(task_name)s[%(task_id)s]:"
                 f" [{a} {b}] %(message)s"
            )
        )

    # ... perform the task, logging with logger,
    # obtained with get_task_logger(__name__)
    # in submodules...


@celery_app.task(ignore_results=True, bind=True)
def task_do_another_something(self):
    ... do not modify the logger here...
```

If two `do_something` task are run concurrently, would the second one override the task logger of the first?

I considered using `@after_setup_task_logger.connect`, but I would have to differentiate between `task_do_something` and `task_do_another_something`, and to retrieve the `a` and `b` parameters.

Comment: Whenever I need some function argument(s) in the logs, I simply log them with INFO or DEBUG level right at the start of the task.

Comment: I want log 2 IDs, so that I can grep them in the logs. But actually your suggestion works: first I grep one of the IDs to get the celery task ID, then I grep the celery taks ID. Simple, I like it! tanks